# Как сохранить позицию скролла у нескольких страниц?

Tags: javascript, html5, webview

Существует несколько страниц связанных между собой ссылками на локальном сервере.Необходимо чтобы при переходе с одной страницы на другую, позиция скролла каждой из них сохранялась независимо друг от друга.То есть я уже использовал jquery с localstorage, но вот только позиция скролла одной страницы влияла на позицию других.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('pagen', scroll);` где n - индекс странички, scroll - прокрутка, и обращаться к ним  `localStorage.getItem('pagen');`

Comment: А при чём тут webview?

Answer (score 0):

Используй ключ, зависящий от страницы, когда сохраняешь значение в localStorage.